# Is it possible to play "Single Race" in "Battle Race" mode?

Tags: sonic-all-stars-racing-transformed

When playing in world tour mode I really enjoyed the few Battle Race maps since they are not just the same "be #1" but rather about avoiding attacks and "killing" your enemies.

However, I could only find it when creating a custom multiplayer game. Is it possible to play battle race against computer enemies on other tracks than the 2 or 3 in world tour?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately, you can only play this with other human players outside of Career for some reason.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Is this information false?